# Plotly: what's the difference between ols and lowess trendlines

Tags: plotly

I'm plotting a dataset with a trendline, but using `ols` vs `lowess` gives me significantly different line shapes. I'm sure this is an expected and perfectly normal result, but I'm afraid I don't understand the significance of the difference. Could someone explain what's going on?
Here's my code using `ols`:

```
fig = px.scatter(df_small, y="Ratio",
                 trendline="ols", 
                 trendline_color_override="red")
fig.show()
```

And here's the plot it produced:
[image]

Using `lowess` gave me this plot:
[image]
For context, my dataset represents the ratio of daily Covid deaths:new infections in the Province of Ontario over the previous 18 months.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't know the details but essentially these are two different methods to fit the data. But what I notice on your graphs is the use of a logarithmic X axis, I'm not sure it's very good here since it makes most of the points appear together on the right side. In case X represents time, it's definitely not a good idea imho.

Comment: Thanks. I did notice the X-axis problem and was going to work on that next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious so I looked it up:

- The first method OLS is actually [Ordinary Least Squares regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) so it just fits a linear regression line. It's probably not what you want in this case since it cannot fit the waves (unless you just want to show the overall trend).
- The lowess method is [local polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression). Since [plotly 5.2.1](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.2.1) `trendline_option` is available to [lowess trendlines](https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/#locally-weighted-scatterplot-smoothing-lowess) which can make the trendline follow the underlying data more closely.

For the record I did a small test with R and ggplot2 which seems to have a better implementation:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

t<-seq(0,12,.1)
noise<-rnorm(121,0,.25)
v<-cos(t)+noise
d<-data.frame(x=t,y=v)
ggplot(d,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+ geom_smooth(method="loess")
```

[image: noisy curve with loess regression in ggplot2]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.